# How to gather frequent update/redraw/layout/refresh operations in SWT/Swing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-handling, swt

I am doing some frequent operations, which require GUI refresh (adding some children to a control).

I can't control the moment when the entire bunch of additions finished, so I can't do update/redraw/layout/refresh at the end and need do it each step.

Simultaneously I need nod do it very frequent, because user need not see each change.

Also each update/redraw/layout/refresh slows the process.

So, I need to decide whether to update/redraw/layout/refresh by time.

I wrote the following general class for SWT, but similar also applicable to Swing.

Is it's logic complete and correct? Especially, will the check `delayedMap.get(doRun) == timer` work correctly in multithreading? It's purpose is to cancel delayed operation in the case if entering the `invokeOnceDelayed()` method is occured between enterings into `TimerTask.run()` and inner `synchronized` block?

```
public class SWTUtilities {

    private static HashMap<Runnable, Timer> delayedMap = new HashMap<Runnable, Timer>();

    public static void invokeLater(Runnable doRun) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(doRun);
    }

    public static void invokeAndWait(Runnable doRun) {
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(doRun);
    }

    public static synchronized void invokeOnceDelayed(final Runnable doRun, long delay) {

        final Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        Timer oldTimer = delayedMap.put(doRun, timer);
        if( oldTimer != null ) {
            oldTimer.cancel();
        }

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized(SWTUtilities.class) {
                    if( delayedMap.get(doRun) == timer ) {
                        invokeLater(doRun);
                    }
                }

            }}, delay);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just delegate to [Display.timerExec](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#timerExec%28int,%20java.lang.Runnable%29) for the implementation of invokeOnceDelayed() method.